# Python for all mathematical and geometric computations libraries, any suggestion apart from my research.thanks

Tags: python

For an Ellipse,
the circumference is given,
thickness is given,
eccentricity is given,
It is a double ellipse problem,
distance between the inner and outer ellipse is given.
find area, major, minor radii, and Python libraries.

Need to solve the problem with the best results. Suggestions welcome.

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mre]